# How to implement "like" functionality of Facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook-like, facebook-android-sdk

I am working on gallery app in which there are lots of images, I want to give functionality to the user that he can like any image within the app and it should reflect in his Facebook profile. For this I want to use the newest SDK(3.0.1).

If he is not logged in, app should take it to the login page of Facebook otherwise by clicking the like button it should reflect in the account of current user.

Please help me to sort out the problem, any help would be appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hai salman...did you implemented the FB like or not...???

Answer (score 0):

Its all right there in Facebook docs :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

What you are describing is 100% possible, just play with examples in the link above.